# SQL Server table taking too much space for specific data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, storage, nvarchar

I have one table in my SQL Server database which has two columns:

```
ItemID1  nvarchar(1200)
ItemID2  nvarchar(1200)
```

Basically I'm expecting here a numeric value to be stored into them (I realized this only after few months the table was created). However some of them are also text - which aren't numbers. And the table size grew to 12.1GB ... And most of them are now stored in the database as `"Unknown ItemID number"`

I realize now that `nvarchar(length)` takes 2 bytes per character + 2 bytes to hold the length of the string). So basically in my case I have length of nvarchar 21 (total string length)  *2  = 42 bytes for all chars in the string +2 bytes to hold the string length = 44 bytes per record...

Now my question here is:

1. If I were to change these string values back to NULL type (since both columns are nullable) - would I save up some space immediately and see it reflected on the DB table size?
2. Would this also reflect on the RAM usage of SQL Server - ie. seeing less usage of RAM on SQL Server?

Thanks everyone

Comment: *"I'm expecting here a numeric value"* Then why are they an `nvarchar(1200)` There are numerical data types in SQL Server for storing numbers. An `nvarchar(1200)` is 2 bytes per character, meaning that datatype is `2*1200 + 2` bytes in size (2402). With an `nvarchar(1200)` for storing a numerical value, you're effectively saying you need to **accurately** store any number between the range `1E+1201-1` and `-1E1200-1` (and waste 1 byte per character, as the characters `0-9`, `-` and `.` aren't unicode characters). Do you *really* need to store such *huge* numbers?

Comment: @Larnu  I don't need such high values - regular integer type would be suitable now for these two columns ( I realize it just now) - but since changing these two column types would create a LOT of mess in my DB and all related applications - I'm looking into an alternative to reduce the table size (by changing these non numeric nvarchars back to NULL). Are you saying that even though I don't store the whole nvarchar length inside these two columns, each of them takes 2402 bytes per record?? Or they are variable - and depending on the string length that are stored inside the columns ?

Comment: @Larnu I made a mistake when creating the table - didn't realize they are only numeric types...

Comment: Even if you fix the datatype (which you most certainly ***should*** do), that space won't be released by the database to the underlying operating system. It'll just create free space in the database file.

Comment: @Larnu even that is good.. What about RAM usage? Would it be reduced as well ?

Comment: Depends whatr you mean by RAM usage. Will it lower the total amount being used by SQL Server? Probably not. SQL Server doesn't release RAM after it's been allocated it (by design). If you don't want SQL Server to use all the ram on the host OS, then limit the RAM it can access. Of course, if you *are* struggling with RAM that might infer you have an underpowered host. The instance, however, would be likely to be less "hungry" for RAM if you change an `nvarchar(1200)` to an `int`, if those columns are referenced frequently in queries.

Comment: @Larnu Yes these two columns are most accessed on the application, which is why I'm considering the change. Would it be "less RAM hungry" - even if I were to set these columns back to NULL - at least for now until I change them to int type?

Comment: @Larnu btw. thanks for the reply - if you wanna write a short reply like this so I can accept  it as correct answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, you need to fix your datatype here. Personally I would do this in a few steps. You've tagged both [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) and [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) here, but I'm *assuming* you're not using completely unsupported software:

```
--Add a column to replicate bad data
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD OldID nvarchar(1200);
GO
--Put bad data in the new column
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET OldID = ItemID1
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, ItemID1) IS NULL;
GO
--Get rid of bad data in the ID column
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ItemID1 = TRY_CONVERT(int, ItemID1);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN ItemID1 int;
GO
--Review bad data
SELECT OldID
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE OldID IS NOT NULL;
GO
--Once reviewed, and action taken, drop the bad column.
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN OldID;
```